# Proving that $g'(x) = 0$ has a unique solution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've been struggling with the following proof for quite some time. Maybe someone will have a fresh eye and will notice something that I don't notice. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Let $f(u,v)\geq0$ be some concave function, increasing in both $u$ and $v$ ($f'_u>0$ and $f'_v>0$). Also, define:
$$g(x) = \gamma \frac{z(x)^2}{2}+ (1-\gamma) f(z(x), x z(x))$$
where $x\in [0,1]$, $\gamma \in [0,1]$, and $z(x) = \dfrac{a+b x}{c + x^2/d}$ (all parameters are positive). I want to show that the following FOC for $g(x)$ has unique solution on the interval $[x_1, x_2]$ where $x_1$ solves $z'(x)=0$ and $x_2$ solves $(xz(x))_x'=0$ (assume both $x_1, x_2 \in [0,1]$ -- we can put some conditions on the parameters for that to happen):
$$\small
g'(x) = \gamma z(x) \frac{\mathrm dz(x)}{\mathrm dx}+(1-\gamma)\left(f'_u(z(x),xz(x)) \frac{\mathrm dz(x)}{\mathrm dx} +f'_v(z(x),xz(x))\frac{\mathrm d(xz(x))}{\mathrm dx}\right) = 0
$$
Given that we are in $[x_1,x_2]$ we know that $z'(x)<0$ and $(xz(x))'_x>0$. Also, we can rewrite FOC as:
$$
-\frac{(xz(x))'_x}{z'(x)} = \frac{\gamma z(x)+(1-\gamma)f'_u(z(x),xz(x))}{(1-\gamma)f'_v(z(x),xz(x))}
$$
The LHS is decreasing concave on $[x_1, x_2]$ and is $\infty$ in the limit at $x_1$ and $0$ at $x_2$. The RHS is positive. I can show that at $x$ satisfying FOC the derivative of the RHS wrt $x$ is positive when $\gamma =0$ (which shows uniqueness at $\gamma=0$) but for higher $\gamma$ such derivative can become negative (based on my numerical experiments). So I am stuck with this approach.

I tried to look at $g''(x)$:
$$
g''(x) = \gamma \left((z'(x))^2+z(x) z''(x)\right) + (1-\gamma) \left(f'_u(\cdots) z''(x) + f'_v(\cdots) (xz(x))''_{xx}\right) + (1-\gamma) \left(f''_{uu}(\cdots) (z'(x))^2 + 2f''_{uv}(\cdots) z'(x)(xz(x))'_x + f''_{vv}(\cdots) ((xz(x))'_x)^2 + \right)
$$
I use $\cdots$ to denote usual arguments $z(x), xz(x)$. The third term is negative (due to concavity of $f$) -- denote it $\Psi$. The first two - I can use FOC to simplify at $x$ which solves FOC and get:
$$
 g''(x) = \Psi + \gamma (z'(x))^2 +(1-\gamma) f'_v(\cdots) \left((xz(x))''_{xx} - \frac{(xz(x))'_x}{z'(x)} z''(x) \right) 
$$
where $\Psi\leq0$. The second term is positive, the third can be shown to be negative using the expression for $z(x)$. Then I am stuck. My claim (which is supported by the numerical experiments) is that $g''(x)\leq0$ at $x$ solving FOC (which would be enough for uniqueness). However, I cannot prove it. One idea was to look at full derivative of $g''(x)$ wrt $\alpha$ but that would require third-order derivatives of $f$ which I don't know anything about.

Let me know if anyone could help. Many thanks!

Comment: If $f(u,v) \geq 0$ then $g(x)=0$ iff $z(x)=f(z(x),xz(x))=0$, right?

Comment: Should be correct

Comment: Oh I see $g'(x)=0$ not $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This proposition is not necessarily true. If $f(u, v) = -cu^2$ for some constant $c > 0$, then for $γ = \dfrac{c}{2c + 1}$,\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \frac{γ}{2} (z(x))^2 + (1 - γ) f(z(x), xz(x))\\
&= \left( \frac{γ}{2} - (1 - γ)c \right) (z(x))^2 = 0. & \forall x \in [0, 1]
\end{align*}
Therefore $g'(x) = 0$ has more than one solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Saad. Sorry, I think I forgot to mention that $f(u,v) \geq 0$. Hence $-cu^2 \leq 0 $ is not possible. I will add clarification to the question.

Comment: @mathisfun This doesn't essentially change the situation since $f(u,v)$ can be taken as $c_1-c_2u^2$ instead with $c_2 > 0$ being large enough (note that $z(x)$ takes values in a finite interval for $x \in [0,1]$).

Comment: I suspect that this is a particular case when $f'_v = 0$. I will assume that both $f'_u>0$ and $f'_v>0$. My claim is that then non-uniqueness never happens.

Comment: could you give an example of $f$ for me to better understand?

Comment: @mathisfun I overlooked one condition in your update, so now I'm not sure if I could find a counterexample. I'm spending more proving your proposition instead.

Comment: thanks a lot! Let me know if I can help anyhow or if you have any thoughts